# Why does the Google structured data testing tool give error for an embedded item property?

Tags: schema.org, microdata, structured-data

My code has markup for [AggregateRating](https://schema.org/aggregateRating) and it is embedded into a Product page that does not have its own [Product](https://schema.org/Product) markup. So I used the 'itemReviewed' property of my AggregateRating markup to specify the Product level data like so..

```
 <div itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">
    <div itemprop="itemReviewed" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
        <meta itemprop="name" content="Haley Lace Bralette">
    </div>
  </div>
```

The google structured data testing tool gives this error "One of offers or review or aggregateRating should be provided", but that error is being given for an AggregateRating element.  Why is it asking for aggregateRating when it is already inside an AggregateRating element?

Comment: It's a limitation in the tool. I'd check if the page gets the rich snippets you are looking for.

Comment: think about it. What is the target of the AggregateRating? With what Type does the AggregateRating have a relationship?